# Are these screws supposed to be in the bottom track of my double-hung vinyl windows?

Tags: windows, window-frame

I noticed there is a 2" screw in the bottom of the track on each of my Andersen windows that were installed side by side to each other. I suspect the screws should not be there since it would allow water get into the screw holes before discharging out from the weep holes.

What could be a possible reason for the installer to do this? Could I remove the screws and patch up the hole with caulk or epoxy or do I need to have the window reinstalled?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they're not part of the window? They don't look like something an installer would've put there.

Comment: I don't see any screws on the track for the other individual windows. It's only in this set of windows that were installed side by side to each other.

Comment: Are there other windows in conjoined groups?

Comment: Do you mean the individual ones? No, they are on their own and not installed next to another window.

Comment: Are these only on the joint between the two window units or are they also on the outside edges? (i.e. is there another window just beyond the jamb we see, or is the other window behind you as you took this picture?) My gut instinct is that these should _not_ be there. If it's a recent install, it should still be under warranty - call the company that installed them and ask for a supervisor to come check it over because you have some questions.

Comment: The screw is in the joint between the two windows and beyond the jamb there is the second window which has another screw near the same location. There are no screws on the outside(opposite) edge of either windows.

Comment: Most single windows will have screws on the sides to hold them to the frame.  Just wondering with two windows, they did not trust the second window to hold, so screwed into the bottom frame?

Comment: If these precede your residence, it’s possible that the screws are left over from a window AC unit installation. Do you have central air, and are window units common in your area?

Comment: @josephorapronobis I have central/split unit AC and as far as I know the windows were installed 1-2 years ago.

Comment: @crip659 that could be and I suspect it was done intentionally for a reason. But the top track was not screwed at all, which doesn't make sense on why they would only screw the bottom track

Comment: The top should usually be on the loose side so the header does not squeeze the window.  One screw in each window might have been thought enough.

Comment: @crip659 Got it. Should I be concerned with water penetration through the screw holes since water drains through that channel?

Comment: A tiny bit, but a good dab of silicon over the top should prevent that.  Clean around the screw first for good bonding, and/or loosen the screw a bit and put some under the head.